# What is the output of the following code and how?

Tags: c

I can't understand the logic of the `for` loop in the function `fun`:

```
long fun(char* s)
{
    long r=0;
    for(;*s; r=(r<<1)|(*s++ - '0'));//explain this 
    return r;
}
int main()
{
    printf("%d ",fun("000001010"));
}
```

Comment: I think it converts your binary from string to long representation

Comment: Logic is quite simple when you break the program down to steps. If you have problem with some specific step, ask about that. But don't expect full explanation, if you haven't shown any effort to solve this first.

Comment: i think it is undefined behaviour to print a long with `%d`.

Comment: Format your code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(;*s; r=(r<<1)|(*s++ - '0'));//explain this
```

is:

```
int r=0;
while(*s){
  int m=*s-'0';
  r=r*2 + m;    
  ++s;
}
```

As commented above It will parse(convert) your binary string to number

Answer (score 1):

It is more or less equivalent to this:

```
long r = 0;
for(size_t i=0; i<strlen(s); i++) // Traverse the string
{
    r = r<<1; // Shift the long representation
    if( s[i] != '0' )  // Is current char 0 or 1
    {
        r = r | 1; // It is 1: append it to long representation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The structure of a for loop is the following:

- Before the first semi-colon you define and/or initialize any values related to the loop
- between the two semi-colons lies the logic that is checked at the start of each loop, if it is true the    loop goes on
- The code after the second semi-colon executes after the loop body is finished

So in your `for` loop there is nothing before the first semi-colon, nothing needs to be initialized, that's normal.

The `*s` will be true (different than 0) for as long as the ASCII value stored there is different than `'0'`, that it the string termination character. So it's the same as saying `strlen(s)!=0`

`r=(r<<1)` performs a bitwise operation on `r`.

`*s++ - '0'` subtracts the character `'0'` from the character pointed to by `s` and then increments the pointer to point to the next character

Answer (score 0):

This for loop will run number of times, the characters inputed in fun() function parameters, e.g. here 9.

The value of r will be decided by the bitwise operation (r<<1),  subtraction (*s++ - '0') and the orring operation | of these two previous operations.

for first five iterations, value of the r will be 0, as leftshift operation on 0 will yeild 0 and ASCII value subtraction of the characters will also come as 0.

for 6th iteration, subtraction will bear value 1, and subsequently r will have 1.
for 7th iteration, leftshift operation (multiplication by 2) will have output 2, so r=2.
for 8th, leftshift operation will have output 4 and subtraction 1, so orring of (1 | 4) will have 5.

and for last iteration, leftshift operation will yeild o/p 10.
So finally You should get 10 as o/p.